# badly placed ()'s when creating oracle database link in tcsh

Tags: oracle, unix, tcsh

```
#my code

echo \
'create database link remotec101 \
connect to "os_user" \
identified by "password" \
using ' \
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP) \
(HOST=c101) \
(PORT=1521)) \
(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)))';'|sqlplus
```

I tried to run some sql in this way and it worked. But when creating database link I got error, saying badly placed ()'s

This code is in tcsh.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: The parentheses are outside the string being echoed, and so is parsed by the shell. Is there a reason you place the connection information outside the string?

Answer (score 2):

The parentheses are not quoted, so they're treated as shell metacharacters.

This:

```
echo \
'create database link remotec101 \
connect to "os_user" \
identified by "password" \
using \
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP) \
(HOST=c101) \
(PORT=1521)) \
(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)));' | sqlplus
```

will feed the following to the `sqlplus` command:

```
create database link remotec101 
connect to "os_user" 
identified by "password" 
using 
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP) 
(HOST=c101) 
(PORT=1521)) 
(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)));
```

But a "here document" is probably cleaner:

```
sqlplus <<'EOF'
create database link remotec101
connect to "os_user"
identified by "password"
using
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)
(HOST=c101)
(PORT=1521))
(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)));
'EOF'
```

If you want the last 4 lines to become a single line of input to `sqlplus`, I think you'll need to put them all on one line in your script.  Or you might find it easier to use the `printf` command to organize your output, for example:

```
printf '%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s %s %s %s\n' \
    'create database link remotec101' \
    'connect to "os_user"' \
    'identified by "password"' \
    'using' \
    '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)' \
    '(HOST=c101)' \
    '(PORT=1521))' \
    '(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)));' | sqlplus
```

This prints the last 4 lines as a single line.  You can adjust the format string as needed.

Comment: I think the OP's issue is wanting those last four lines to be a string within a string

Comment: @Dan: I'm not sure what "a string within a string" means.  It would help if the OP told us exactly what he wants the `sqlplus` command to see on its stdin.  (It would also help if I knew what `sqlplus` expects.)

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was, they're passing a string to the `echo` command right? But within that, specifically the part with the parentheses, they need a string. Or in other words, those two apostrophes that look like they don't belong are actually part of the body of what's meant to be `echo`ed. I posted a reply that escapes them with `\\` but apparently that doesn't work in tcsh.

Comment: @Dan: Hmm.  The real question is, exactly what input should be given to `sqlplus`?  Given that, we can figure out how to provide it.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. You have to utilize the fact that tcsh supports both quote types and `echo` allows multiple arguments:

```
echo 'create database link remotec101 \
connect to "os_user" \                                                          
identified by "password" \                                                      
using ' "'" ' ( DESCRIPTION= ( ADDRESS= ( PROTOCOL=TCP )
 ( HOST=c101 ) 
 ( PORT=1521 ) ) 
 ( CONNECT_DATA= ( SID=XE ) ) ) ' "';"
```